# How to differentiate between a successful transaction and a failed transaction to display the transaction status in the UI?

Tags: nearprotocol

I am trying to display transaction status based on the tx hash in the UI after the user makes a transaction.

I noticed that the method `ft_resolve_transfer` result is a value when the tx is successful and is 0 when the tx fails.

When I take a look at the response JSON given after i run this command

```
NEAR_ENV=mainnet  near tx-status DG4vGH3EagGQJsdRTSjWLHxZYrriHbki4imqFBeJzSc1 --accountId skiran017.near
```

the JSON is almost similar to the one i get when a transaction is successful.

is there any specific key-value pair i need to look into to find the difference between a success and a failed tx.?

failed tx: https://explorer.mainnet.near.org/transactions/DG4vGH3EagGQJsdRTSjWLHxZYrriHbki4imqFBeJzSc1

successful tx:
https://explorer.mainnet.near.org/transactions/8WRJ39F1UGB5fXcLBUS5tz5mmmis4czL9U8S1SoddiNj

Answer (score 1):

Currently I fixed this by leveraging `status: { SuccessValue: 'IjAi' }`. We can find this in JSON object that is returned when querying for transaction status using txHash and accountId.

SuccessValue key has a value in base64. I decoded that to ASCI and check wheather its not zero. So far all the non zero value are successful transactions.

```
function getTxStatus(txHash: string, accountId: string) {
    if (!txHash || !accountId) {
      return;
    }
    checkTransactionStatus(txHash, accountId).then((res: any) => {
      const status: any = res.status;
      const data: string | undefined = status.SuccessValue;

      if (data) {
        const buff = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
        const value = buff.toString('ascii');

        console.log(value); // check this for non zero value
      }
    });
  }
```

Thanks to Ref Finance team, took reference from their code.

Note: when the token does not have storage deposit, ft_sotrage is called to store the token, in this case the txHashes is an array where in the txHash on 0 index represents storage related details, the second txHash is on first index which contains tx details.